# Recursively defining an N-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, recursion

I am trying to recursively define a numpy array of N dimensions. After researching for several hours, I have came across a couple of ways this might work (np.append and np.concatenate), however neither of these has given me the desired output. I've been getting either:
`[-0.6778734  -0.73517866 -0.73517866  0.6778734 ]` (1-d array) or
`[array([-0.6778734 , -0.73517866]), array([-0.73517866,  0.6778734 ])]` (a list of arrays)

My Input:

```
[(1.2840277121727839, array([-0.6778734, -0.73517866])), 
    (0.049083398938327472, array([-0.73517866, 0.6778734 ]))]
```

Desired output:

```
array([-0.6778734, -0.73517866], [-0.73517866, 0.6778734])
```

Is it possible to create a numpy array from arrays, because converting them to lists and back to arrays seems computationally inefficient?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean a 2-d array?

Comment: Well an n x n or n x k dimensional array is what I am going for, I used a 2 x 2 as a simple example to reduce my computational time for the rest of my algorithm while in prototyping stage.

Comment: I think @Dunes question comes from your desired output being impossible.  I think you are missing an extra pair of braces that would make it a 2-d array: `array([[-0.6778734, -0.73517866], [-0.73517866, 0.6778734]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is a list of tuples, each tuple consisting of a number and an array.  For some reason you want to throw away the number, and just combine the arrays into a larger array - is that right?

```
In [1067]: x=[(1.2840277121727839, np.array([-0.6778734, -0.73517866])), 
    (0.049083398938327472, np.array([-0.73517866, 0.6778734 ]))]

In [1068]: x
Out[1068]: 
[(1.2840277121727839, array([-0.6778734 , -0.73517866])),
 (0.04908339893832747, array([-0.73517866,  0.6778734 ]))]
```

A list comprehension does a nice job of extracting the desired elements for the tuples:

```
In [1069]: [y[1] for y in x]
Out[1069]: [array([-0.6778734 , -0.73517866]), array([-0.73517866,  0.6778734 ])]
```

and `vstack` is great for combining arrays into a larger one.

```
In [1070]: np.vstack([y[1] for y in x])
Out[1070]: 
array([[-0.6778734 , -0.73517866],
       [-0.73517866,  0.6778734 ]])
```

`vstack` is just `concatenate` with an added step that ensures the inputs are 2d.

`np.array([y[1] for y in x])` also works, since you are adding a dimension.

I'm assuming that `array([-0.6778734, -0.73517866], [-0.73517866, 0.6778734])` has a typo - that it is missing a set of `[]`.  The 2nd parameter to `np.array` is the dtype, not another list.

Note that both `np.array` and `np.concatentate` take a list.  It can be list of lists, or list of arrays.  It doesn't make much difference.  And at this stage don't worry about computational efficiency.  Any time you combine the data from 2 or more arrays there will be copying.  Arrays have a fixed size, and can't 'grow' without making a new copy.

---

```
In [1074]: np.concatenate([y[1] for y in x]).reshape(2,2)
Out[1074]: 
array([[-0.6778734 , -0.73517866],
     [-0.73517866,  0.6778734 ]])
```

Lists are effectively 1d, so `np.concatenate` joins them on that dimension, producing a 4 element 1d array.  `reshape` corrects that.  `vstack` makes them both `(1,2)` and does a concatenate on the 1st dimension.

Another expression that joins the arrays on a new dimension:

```
np.concatenate([y[1][None,...] for y in x], axis=0)
```

The `[None,...]` adds a new dimension at the start.

Comment: Thank you, if I understand correctly you are saying that vstack only works for the n x 2 dimensional array? Otherwise, I should use concatenate.

Comment: I tried `np.concatenate([y[1] for y in ei_rearranged])` which didn't work, but the np.array works and I assume will work for N dimensions.

Comment: You need to reshape the result of `concatenate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2])
b = np.array([3, 4])
print(repr(np.vstack((a, b))))
```

Gives:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: `a = ei_rearranged[0][1]
    b = ei_rearranged[1][1]
    print(np.vstack((a,b)))` <br/> gives the output: `[[-0.6778734  -0.73517866]
 [-0.73517866  0.6778734 ]]` <br/> where ei_rearranged = [(1.2840277121727839, array([-0.6778734, -0.73517866])), 
    (0.049083398938327472, array([-0.73517866, 0.6778734 ]))] regardless I still need to define this recursively so that I can get n dimensions. Still weird it isn't including a comma between rows.

Comment: There are no commas anywhere. To get the commas, try: `print(repr(arr))`.

Comment: Gives: [array([-0.6778734 , -0.73517866]), array([-0.73517866,  0.6778734 ])]

Answer (score 0):

You can form the desired 2D array given a list `input_data` of the form

```
input_data = [(1.2840277121727839, np.array([-0.6778734, -0.73517866])), 
              (0.049083398938327472, np.array([-0.73517866, 0.6778734 ]))]
```

via

```
nparr = np.array(list(row[1] for row in input_data))
```